# Why wrong order execution system.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs

Why system.js first performs `__extends` and then initializes?

Although I see no initialization at all since the first thing is called the `__extends` and throw out errors. How to fix it?

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {

        console.log('set:__extends', d, b); // set:__extends undefined undefined

    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};System.register(['some.js'], function(exports_1) {

    console.log('set:exports', exports_1); // #####

    var some_js_1;
    var Index;
    return {
        setters:[
            function (_some_js_1) {

                console.log('set:setters'); // #####

                some_js_1 = _some_js_1;
            }],
        execute: function() {

            console.log('set:execute'); // #####

            Index = (function (_super) {

                console.log('set:before __extends'); // #####

                __extends(Index, _super);
                function Index() {
                    _super.call(this);
                    //console.log('some', some_js_1.SomeSuperClass);
                }
                return Index;
            })(some_js_1.SomeSuperClass);

            console.log('set:before exports_1'); // #####

            exports_1("default", Index);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What error are you getting? There is nothing wrong with `__extends` being before `function Index()` because function declarations are hoisted.

Comment: @ loganfsmyth: `console.log('set:__extends', d, b); // set:__extends undefined undefined`

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a jsbin or something? It seems to work as I'd expect: https://jsbin.com/hejoxatiru/edit?js,console

Comment: There are cases where I could see `b` being `undefined` but in that code, `d` would never be undefined ever.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: I love You!!! If you omit the __extends below the register, the works. But this is a mistake typescript, in fact it generates the wrong modules System... Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but if that helped, great :)

Comment: @shatal: So this is [tag:typescript], not [tag:ecmascript-6]?

Comment: @Bergi: right, this is typescript, but in a compiled form.